# Save buddypress xprofile data to author meta

Tags: buddypress, user-meta, author-template

I have created a buddypress extended profile field "description" and would like to save the data entered to the "descripion" profile field of the user (DEfault wordpress Biography description field) when user fills / edit the buddypress field.

Any clue .. how to achieve this?

Actually I'll be retriving in template as `get_the_author_meta('description',$author_id) ;`

So i want that the `xprofile` field save to this meta field as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this action hook found in `buddypress/bp-xprofile/classes/class-bp-xprofile-profiledata.php`

```
do_action_ref_array( 'xprofile_data_after_save', array( $this ) );
```

You'll need to use the actual `field_id` for your xprofile description. This example assumes it is `25`. You can get the `field_id`by going to `wp-admin > Users > Profile Fields` and clicking 'Edit' on that field. The `field_id` will appear in the browser url.

```
function echoashu_save_description( $obj ) {

    if ( $obj->field_id == 25 ) {
        update_user_meta( $obj->user_id, 'description', $obj->value );
    }
}
add_action( 'xprofile_data_after_save', 'echoashu_save_description' );
```

Comment: that's what i was looking for
I'll test that out :) , just one thing $obj->user_id ( is it logged in user's id or retrived from the the user who's profile is being eidted

Comment: It's the ID of the user who's profile is being edited.